How to fix "pointer ‘old’ may be used after ‘realloc’ [-Wuse-after-free]" warning in C?
I'm encountering a warning in my C code while trying to reallocate memory using realloc. The specific warning is:
lib/gc.c: In function ‘gcLocalRealloc’:
lib/gc.c:625:9: warning: pointer ‘old’ may be used after ‘realloc’ [-Wuse-after-free]
  625 |         gcLocalPop ( gc,old ) ;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib/gc.c:621:11: note: call to ‘realloc’ here
  621 |     ptr = (void*) realloc ( ptr,SIZE ) ;

Here is the code that's causing the issue:
void* gcLocalRealloc(gc_t *gc, void* ptr, size_t SIZE) {
    //assert(SIZE!=0); // realloc(array, 0) is not equivalent to free(array).
    if (SIZE == 0) {
        gcFree(ptr);
        return ptr = NULL;
    }
    
    assert(SIZE > 0);
    
    if (ptr == NULL) return gcLocalMalloc(gc, SIZE);

    void* old = ptr;
    
    ptr = (void*) realloc(ptr, SIZE);

    if (ptr != NULL) {
        gcLocalPop(gc, old);
        gcLocalPush(gc, ptr, SIZE);
        assert(ptr != NULL);
    }

    return ptr;
}

The compiler warns that the pointer old may be used after it is freed by realloc. How can I fix this warning while maintaining the functionality of reallocating memory and updating my garbage collection?
Thanks in advance for your help!

If realloc() was successful, you must not use old. But you do, in gcLocalPop(gc, old);

Note this means you may not use old even if you do not dereference it (e.g. as a key in a lookup table).  But it seems that the solution here may be as simple as just doing the Pop before the realloc, and the Push afterwards.

The (void *) cast on the result of realloc() is redundant (unnecessary).  Similarly, the assert(SIZE > 0); is redundant; SIZE is of type size_t which is an unsigned type (so it can't be negative), and you've dealt with SIZE == 0 so at the point of the assertion, SIZE must be greater than 0.  Style guide: most often, all-caps names are used for macro values and enumeration values.  It's unusual to use an all-caps variable name.  Not wrong, but unusual.

If realloc() is successful, you should use ptr rather than old. The only time you need to use old is when realloc() fails, you should return it instead of ptr. Usually it's easier to use a new variable for the result of realloc(), and assign it to the original value after you check for success.

Once you call realloc, if it returns a non-null value, then the value of old (which contains the prior pointer value) becomes indeterminate.  As such, attempting to use this value (even if you don't dereference it) can cause undefined behavior.
What you should do in this case is always call gcLocalPop before calling realloc, and just call gcLocalPush whether successful or not.
void* gcLocalRealloc(gc_t *gc, void* ptr, size_t SIZE) {
    if (SIZE == 0) {
        gcFree(ptr);
        return ptr = NULL;
    }
    
    assert(SIZE > 0);
    if (ptr == NULL) return gcLocalMalloc(gc, SIZE);

    int old_size = gcLocalPop(gc, ptr);
    void* old = ptr;
    
    ptr = realloc(ptr, SIZE);

    if (ptr != NULL) {
        gcLocalPush(gc, ptr, SIZE);
        return ptr;
    } else {
        gcLocalPush(gc, old, old_size);
        return old;
    }
}

Note that you'll have to modify gcLocalPop to return the size of the removed item in case you need to put it back in the case of a realloc failure.

The error case should return NULL instead of old, so the caller knows whether the new number of bytes is available. Alternatively, just abort if realloc fails since correctly handling this error without aborting is very difficult.

By implementing the fix as indicated, the warning disappears, and Valgrind returns zero memory leaks


The compiler warns that the pointer old may be used after it is freed by realloc. How can I fix this warning while maintaining the functionality of reallocating memory and updating my garbage collection?

Well, you make a copy of the old pointer, which is no longer usable (if your allocation succeded) and use it after realloc() is called.... not using it more (better, make a copy only for the purpose of having access to the old pointer in case realloc() fails, but only for that purpose)
If realloc succeeds, the old pointer is not usable anymore.  But the pointer is still saved in the old variable.
IMHO the problem is in the semantics of gcLocalPop(), as it requires the old pointer that, probably is not valid.  Indeed, the gcLocalPop() routine should not get the (invalid) value of old, it is possible that you want to pass the address of old to replace it, instead.  If you are pushing the values of the pointers to store some idea of the allocated size, then you are incorrect, once the pointer was deallocated, dereferencing it is a mistake.  You cannot trust any value stored in the old position, it can have been destroyed by the reallocating routine (most probably to detect that you are still using the old pointer somewhere :), this was probably the error message you got about)
If you are using a stack to store values of pointers, the interface to gcLocalPop(gc, old); should never be to pass it the value to be popped, but just pop&discard the value in the top of the stack.  This doesn't require to pass it the value (as it should be in the stack already) you want to replace the top value of the stack, then do:
    gcLocalPop(gc);  /* we are not interested in the old value */
    gcLocalPush(gc, ptr);

and gcLocalPop() function should take the reference to the garbage collector only, and, optionally, return the top value (you will be able to check ---for error detection purposes--- if the returned value from the top of the stack is equal to the one contained in the old variable, but nothing else)  so gcLocalPop() should have an interface like the following:
    void *gcLocalPop(GarbageCollector gc);

as you are getting something from the stack, not pushing.

Yes, the warning has been resolved as described. Thank you.
